# How should I know which form is loaded inside the panel programmatically

Tags: c#, forms, panel

I have a form which consists a panel and three buttons called save and loadForm1, loadForm2. When I click loadForm1(2) button it loads the particular form into the panel.

But I have only one save button. I want to save the data which are on forms in the panel into the database..

How can I access the particular form? (I mean I want to know which form is loaded in the panel when I click the save button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var form = Panel1.Controls.OfType<Form>().First();

if(form.Name =="Form1") // or you can check ID
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Panel has Children property, which is array actually. Also every control has Tag property, you can write here whatever you want. So when you load some control into panel just initialize its Tag property with some value and when save button is pressed check its tag property value.

```
var form1 = new SomeControl();
form1.Tag = 1;
yourPanel.Children.Add(form1);

// and then somewhere in code
if (yourPanel.Children[0].Tag == 1) 
{
    // control 1 action
}
```

It's the easiest way I think.